# I want to stop processing subsequent messages in spring-kafka once I encounter an exception

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

When I encounter exception the kafka listener must not process new messages. It should wait till the exception condition gets resolved (may be manual intervention required) and then start consuming messages.

Config

```
@Bean("consumerContainerFactory")
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, ? extends SpecificRecordBase>
    kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {

        String concurrency = consumer == null ?  "1" : consumer.getConcurrency();
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, ? extends SpecificRecordBase> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();

        factory.setConsumerFactory(new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs()));
        factory.setConcurrency(Integer.parseInt(concurrency));
        factory.setCommonErrorHandler(getDefaultErrorHandler());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL);
        log.info("Kafka Consumer Created Successfully");
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultErrorHandler getDefaultErrorHandler() {
        DefaultErrorHandler defaultErrorHandler = new DefaultErrorHandler();
        defaultErrorHandler.setAckAfterHandle(false);
        return defaultErrorHandler;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {

        ConsumerConfiguration config = consumer == null ? new ConsumerConfiguration() : consumer;
        Map<String, Object> consumerProperties = new HashMap<>(kafkaCommonConfigs());

        consumerProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        consumerProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        consumerProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(config.getMaxPollInterval())) {
            consumerProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG,
                    Integer.parseInt(config.getMaxPollInterval()));
        }

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(config.getSessionTimeout())) {
            consumerProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG,
                    Integer.parseInt(config.getSessionTimeout()));
        }
        consumerProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        consumerProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, EARLIEST);
        consumerProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.ISOLATION_LEVEL_CONFIG, READ_COMMITTED);
        consumerProperties.put(SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, true);

        return consumerProperties;
    }
```

Listener

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "#{topicName}",
            groupId = "#{consumerGroupId}",
            containerFactory = "consumerContainerFactory")
    public void listenProgramNumberMessages(ConsumerRecord<String, Event> record,
                                            Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
        try {
            var event = record.value();
            log.info("Received message: {}", event);
            if(isProcessingAllowed(event)){
                log.info("Consumed message: {}" , marketChannelCustomerChoiceEvent);
                if(event.getCustomerChoice().getAbbreviatedDescription()
                        .contains("BLENDER")){
                    throw new RuntimeException();
                }
                



listenerService.doSomething();
                acknowledgment.acknowledge();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception occurred :", e);
            acknowledgment.nack(Duration.ofMillis(1000));
        }
    }
```

I am testing it by explicitly throwing RuntimeException. So if i change/publish something associated to BLENDER i get exception in logs and lag count is increased, but when I change/publish that is not associated to BLENDER the message gets consumed. I want the message to be stuck. Is there a way to do it ? Spring-Kafka version is 2.8.1 Spring boot 2.7

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a `CommonContainerStoppingErrorHandler` (which completely stops the container, which can be restarted via the `ListenerContainerEndpointRegistry` bean) or use a `FixedBackOff` with infinite retries (`Long.MAX_VALUE`) and a suitable retry interval in the `DefaultErrorHandler`; the default back off is 9 retries with no interval.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#container-stopping-error-handlers

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#default-eh

Comment: Thanks! for responding to my query, 
Below is the status of my trials
FixedBackOff with infinite retries is retrying the error message no doubt in that, but when I sent a non-errored message the Listener was consuming it, so it did not meet my requirements.
When I added ContainerStoppingErrorHandler it showed as deprecated, are there any new options to achieve blocking of all messages once I encounter an error.

Comment: Typo (it is correct in the documentation link) `CommonContainerStoppingErrorHandler`.  `>but when I sent a non-errored message ` - that doesn't make any sense, unless `concurrency > 1`; while in retry mode, the same record is redelivered and we never move forward; when using `concurrency`; only the consumer that has the error will block. You should also upgrade to 2.9.13, which is compatible with Spring Boot 2.7.x. See the matrix here: https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka#overview

Comment: factory.setCommonErrorHandler(new DefaultErrorHandler(new FixedBackOff(1, UNLIMITED_ATTEMPTS)));
I tried this in my kafkaListenerContainerFactory method with ack mode as manual

Comment: As I said, that will only achieve what you want if `concurrency=1`. BTW, 1 there means 1 millisecond.

Comment: String concurrency = consumer == null ?  "1" : consumer.getConcurrency();
 factory.setConcurrency(Integer.parseInt(concurrency));
Concurreny is 1,  and in consumer config is am fetching from yml file where it has a concurrecy of 1

these are properties consumer:
    maxPollInterval: 300000
    sessionTimeout: 500000
    maxPollRecords: 100
    offset: 1
    concurrency: 1
does any other property influence it

Comment: I see you are new here; don't put code in comments; it is too hard to read; edit the question instead and comment that you have done so. "influence it" - influence what exactly. Turn on DEBUG logging to see how it works.

Comment: I now see that you are using manual acks and `nack()` - the error handler is not involved there - only when the listener throws an exception. But, again, you will not see subsequent records until the failing one stops failing (with concurrency = 1). Throw the exception instead of catching and nacking and the error handler will do its work.